# Racket's `in-range` is not working as expected

Tags: scheme, racket

Why does the following result in an error?

```
(println ((in-range 1 10 2)))

;; results in:

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<stream>
  arguments...: [none]
```

Is `println` not a procedure?

The following works as expected:

```
(for (( x  (in-range 1 10 2))) (println x))
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a couple of incorrect parentheses - remember: in Scheme `()` around an expression means *procedure application* (and that's what the error states); try this instead:

```
(println (in-range 1 10 2))
=> #<stream>
```

Beware! the above outputs a *stream*; it works in the second snippet because `for` consumes it. If what you intended was to print the list of values in the given range, this is the way to do it:

```
(println (range 1 10 2))
=> '(1 3 5 7 9)
```

Comment: What is the use of stream from in-range?

Comment: @mso streams are a _lazy_ sequence of elements, meaning: we don't generate all of the elements at the same time, just the one we need at a time. This can potentially save memory, and in principle allows us to operate on infinite data.